# Key->Hash in Apex Web Service HTTP inputHttpHeaders_x

Tags: web-services, soap, http-headers, apex-code

I am using Apex to perform a Web Service Callout.

The web service requires these HTTP headers in the following format.

passport.**username**

passport.**password**

passport.**token**

Is there a good way to do the equivalent of the following? This code wouldn't work but should make clear what I am trying to accomplish.

```
    c.inputHttpHeaders_x = new Map<String, String>();

    c.passport = new Map<String, String>();

    c.passport.put('username', '123');
    c.passport.put('password', '456');
    c.passport.put('token', '789');

    c.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('passport',c.passport);
```

Thanks in advance!